# File Uploading not working in IE 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Uploading a file is not working in I.E. 10: I got an '*Error Invalid argument*' error in the console.
It is working in Mozila and Chrome.

```
$frm.css({display: "inline-block", float: 'left'});
alert('two start');
$frm[0].action = '../rest/file/upload';
alert('three start');
alert('fore start');
$frm[0].enctype='multipart/formdata'; // Error Line
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Isn't it `multipart/form-data` instead of `multipart/formdata` for the value of `enctype`?

Answer (score 3):

Try `multipart/form-data` instead of `multipart/formdata`:

```
            $frm.css({display: "inline-block", float: 'left'});
            alert('two start');
            $frm[0].action = '../rest/file/upload';
            alert('three start');
            alert('fore start');
            $frm[0].enctype='multipart/form-data';
```